# Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

Tags: android, android-studio, programación-móvil, ide

Me sale este error al ejecutar el emulador de android, lo raro es que no es el típico error que al IDE le falta instalar HAX, porque lo revise y ya lo tengo instalado, entonces no se porque sigue saliendo el error, ¿A qué se de deberá?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: lo tienes instalado en el sdk manager?

Comment: si, ahí lo tengo instalado

Comment: Probablemente no esta activada la virtualizacion de hardware en tu computadora. Inicia en el BIOS y activa la opcion, normalmente viene como "Hardware virtualization"